# Reset cs cart admin password

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, cs-cart

I am trying to reset the admin password on a cs cart installation. I tried some advices found on internet (set password using md5 in database), but none worked. The CS-Cart version is 4.2.3. I think they changed to an encryption based on salt.

Comment: If they're using MD5 for passwords, I'm seriously concerned about the security of this product. That's so easy to crack it's ridiculous.

Comment: No, they used md5 in previous versions. I see they have a salt for every user.

Comment: They can salt that all day long, it doesn't change the fact that MD5 is trash and worthless for security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please update table for admin user

```
cscart_users
```

fields

```
password = MD5( YOUR PASSWORD ) 
salt =
```

- salt field should be empty
- prefix of the database and be different